# Как привязать мировую систему отсчета мыши к камере Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

На нажатие левой кнопки мыши куб получает её координаты, т.е. двигается в сторону нажатия. Всё работает, но когда поворачиваю угол камеры (зажатая правая кн. мыши), системы отсчета мыши и камеры не совпадают, и движением куба трудно управлять. Можно как либо привязать систему координат камеры и мыши друг к другу, чтобы ось была неподвижна относительно меня?

```
from ursina import *        
app = Ursina()  
cub = Entity(model='cube')
def input(key):         
    if held_keys['left mouse']:
        cub.position=(mouse.position[0]*10, mouse.position[1], mouse.position[2]*10)
ec = EditorCamera(rotation_smoothing=0, enabled=True, zoom_speed = 0.2)
app.run()
```